# Add class if HTML tag is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add a hidden class in my JS if the span is empty, but if it isnt show the content.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="uploadControls">              
  <br><span id="uploadsError" class="validErrors smarterr"></span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#uploadControls').find('span').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':empty'))
        $(this).addClass('.hidden');      
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple typo!

```
$(this).addClass('.hidden'); 
                  ^
```

The class name string has a `.`. addClass is not a selector, just the name[s] to be added.

It should be

```
$(this).addClass('hidden');
```

and you can just do it with the selector, no each/find is needed.

```
$("#uploadControls span:empty").addClass("hidden");
```